# How to store a Dataframe in a Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Dataframe that extends column-wise by using a for-loop.
now I want to store certain "stages" of the evolving DF somehow and I thought it would be the best to use a Dictionary.

to give you a picture:

```
df_dict={}
for i in range(1,13):
    df=pd.read_csv('./test.csv').iloc[:,0:i*4-1]
```

so I want to store this as "first stage" of the df:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
  1        3        5        7
  2        4        6        8
```

in the "second stage":

```
col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6     col7     col8
  1        3        5        7        9        11       13       15
  2        4        6        8        10       12       14       16
```

3rd stage contains 12 cols:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6     col7     col8     ...
  1        3        5        7        9        11       13       15     ...
  2        4        6        8        10       12       14       16     ...
```

Ongoing till the 12th stage contains 48 cols.

So in general I want to store in the Dict these stages where every new stage has 4 more columns.
And I need to be able to use these different Dataframes seperatly later.

I know that

```
df_dict.update({i, df})
```

doesn't work since DFs are mutable, but I did not manage to find a way to work around it.

I'm new to Python so please by gentle with me.
Cheers!

**EDIT:**
I wasn't searching the Idea of how to get variable variables since I allready mentioned that I want to use a Dict, but I was looking for a way of storing my Dataframe in a Dict.

Comment: Did you try 'df.to_dict()' ?

Comment: How I understand you want to add this dataFrame into dict, so you can transform your datafreame into dict with this df.to_dict(), and after that update your dict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to assign each `DataFrame` in loop:

```
df_dict={}
for i in range(1,13):
    df=pd.read_csv('./test.csv').iloc[:,0:i*4-1]
    df_dict[i] = df
```

Another solution is use `dictionary comprehension`:

```
df_dict = {i: pd.read_csv('./test.csv').iloc[:,0:i*4-1] for i in range(1,13)}
```